# In "The Rings of Power," what is Halbrand referring to when he says "The One?"

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

In the last episode of the show *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power*, during the scene between Halbrand and Galadriel, Halbrand makes a reference to "The One", but I don't understand what it can be.

> "When Morgoth was defeated, it was as if a great, clenched fist had released its grasp from my neck.  And in the stillness of that first sunrise, at last I felt the light of **The One** again.  And I knew if ever I was to be forgiven…  That I had to heal everything that I had helped ruin."

As for me it cannot be The One ring as it has not been forged yet.
Moreover, Halbrand says "The One again", so it means it's something or someone that already exists.

Does anyone know the reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **The One is Eru**

In-show, we have the evidence that Adar says, in Episode 6 [**EDIT:** I originally somehow got a misquote of this, I cannot recall how: I had "children" instead of "creations", hence the following discussion.]

> We are creations of the One, Master of the Secret Fire, the same as you.

There is only one time in Tolkien where he talks about "children of the One", and that is in the [Quenya term *Eruhíni*](https://www.elfdict.com/wt/500068), or "children of Eru", referring to the Elves and the Men collectively (and technically also the Dwarves, the "children of [his] adoption"). The name "Eru" itself [translates to](https://www.elfdict.com/wt/106001) "the One", and the famous opening line of Ainulindalë, the first section of the 1977 *Silmarillion*, is this:

> There was Eru, the One, who in Arda is called Ilúvatar

The One here is also called 'Master of the Secret Fire', and the 'Secret Fire' is also sometimes called the Flame Imperishable. The Secret Fire is of course referenced by Gandalf in Moria, called himself a 'servant of the Secret Fire'. The Ainulindalë also says

> [Melkor] had gone often alone into the void places seeking the Imperishable Flame; for desire grew hot within him to bring into Being things of his own, and it seemed to him that Ilúvatar took no thought for the Void, and he was impatient of its emptiness. Yet he found not the Fire, for it is with Ilúvatar.

The origin of this particular line in the show is in Tolkien's struggles later in life to find a consistent origin story for the orcs that was consistent with his own personal philosophical and theological ideas: Morgoth couldn't have created the Orcs as in early versions of the Legendarium, because Tolkien held that evil could not create life—both in-universe, and in the real world. But Orcs were clearly rational beings, and the idea that Orcs were corrupted Elves led to the idea that their *fëar*, their souls, should be able to go to the Halls of Mandos in the West. But the protagonists in Tolkien's stories kill Orcs with no mercy, and even Gimli and Legolas make a game out of how many, at Helm's Deep. Tolkien tried many ideas and it's not clear if he settled on a final satisfactory one. Christopher Tolkien went with the 'corrupted Elves' version (from the 1950s), but makes it a tiny bit ambiguous in the 1977 *Silmarillion*, just for the sake of getting the most consistent, usable material.

So the showrunners are both relying on the published words of Tolkien when Adar says the Orcs/Uruks are of the Eruhíni (the Children of Eru), namely when Frodo says on the Stairs of Cirith Ungol:

> The Shadow that bred them can only mock, it cannot make: not real new things of its own. I don’t think it gave life to the orcs, it only ruined them and twisted them; and if they are to live at all, they have to live like other living creatures.

but they are also leaning into the *unpublished* writings of Tolkien to show the dangers of this idea, that Orcs should be as a result treated as rational beings with the capacity for redemption. Tolkien needed 'forces of evil', and so was trying to find a way around the Orcs being, essentially, genetically Elves, but never solved the problem.

[To mind my mind it's one of the coolest moments of the show.]

Comment: Dwarves were "Adopted Children of Ilúvatar" and couldn't pass into the West like elves or men and even had a separate afterlife (though the elves thought they had none). Definitely second class beings; another of Tolkien's bigotries. The elves in Silmarillion hunted the petty-dwarves (undersized outcasts) believing them animals at first but later when discovering that they were dwarves, kept it up and stole their homes and lands.

[definitely that speech of Adar's was the coolest moment of the show]

Answer (score 23):

I do not think that the makers of the show have given an explanation, but I think this must refer to Eru Ilúvatar, the supreme deity of Arda. In particular, Eru means "The One" (or "Alone"), while the epithet Ilúvatar means "Father of All" in Quenya.

Halbrand is recalling the time when Morgoth was defeated:

> it was if a great clenched fist had released its grasp from my neck,
> and in the stillness of that first sunlight at last I felt the light
> of the One again.

> At that time Halbrand/Sauron repented from his evil and turned back to the light (although some doubted how genuine his repentance was), and so felt the presence of Eru again.

Comment: Further support is the following line from LotR, Appendix A, towards the end of the section on Númenor: "But when Ar-Pharazôn set foot upon the shores of Aman the Blessed, the Valar laid down their Guardianship and **called upon the One**, and the world was changed" — The bit with added emphasis clearly refers to Eru.

Comment: Supreme Deity of "Eä".

Answer (score 9):

### "The One" refers to Eru, the God in Tolkien's universe.

There are two places where *The Rings of Power* refers to The One.

- Galadriel interrogating Adar.

  > GALADRIEL: They are not children, they are slaves.
  > ADAR: But each one has a name. A heart. A heart.
  > GALADRIEL: A heart created by Morgoth.
  > ADAR: **We are creations of The One, Master of the Secret Fire, the same as   you.** As worthy of the breath of life, and just as worthy of a home. Soon... This land will be ours. Then, you will understand.
  > <sub>The Rings of Power - Episode 6 - Udûn [49:20-49:50]</sub>
- Halbrand talking to Galadriel in her mind.

  > HALBRAND: When Morgoth was defeated, it was as if a great, clenched fist had released its grasp from my neck. And in the stillness of that first sunrise, at last, **I felt the light of The One again.** And I knew if ever I was to be forgiven... That I had to heal everything that I had helped ruin.
  > <sub>The Rings of Power - Episode 8 - Alloyed [44:50 - 45:25]</sub>

Both cases are referring Eru/Ilúvatar, the God and Creator in Tolkien's universe. (In other places Rings of Power has used the terms "gods". This would be referring to the Valar, a group of angelic powers who are under Eru.)

This is most easily explained using *The Silmarillion*, where Eru is introduced, identified as the Creator, and directly associated with the phrase "secret fire".

> **There was Eru, the One, who in Arda is called Ilúvatar;** and he made first the Ainur, the Holy Ones, that were the offspring of his thought, and they were with him before aught else was made. And he spoke to them, propounding to them themes of music; and they sang before him, and he was glad.
> ...
> Never since have the Ainur made any music like to this music, though it has been said that a greater still shall be made before Ilúvatar by the choirs of the Ainur and the Children of Ilúvatar after the end of days. Then the themes of Ilúvatar shall be played aright, and take Being in the moment of their utterance, for all shall then understand fully his intent in their part, and each shall know the comprehension of each, and **Ilúvatar shall give to their thoughts the secret fire,** being well pleased.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - "Ainulindalë"</sub>

> **In the beginning Eru, the One, who in the Elvish tongue is named Ilúvatar,** made the Ainur of his thought; and they made a great Music before him. In this Music the World was begun; for Ilúvatar made visible the song of the Ainur, and they beheld it as a light in the darkness. And many among them became enamoured of its beauty, and of its history which they saw beginning and unfolding as in a vision. Therefore Ilúvatar gave to their vision Being, and set it amid the Void, and **the Secret Fire was sent to burn at the heart of the World;** and it was called Eä.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - "Valaquenta"</sub>

> *Eru* 'The One', 'He that is Alone': Ilúvatar.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - "Index"</sub>

Amazon reportedly does not have the rights to *The Silmarillion* itself, but both "The One" and "the Secret Fire" appear directly in the text of *The Lord of the Rings*, even if less explicit as to what they mean.

> 'You cannot pass,' he said. The orcs stood still, and a dead silence fell. '**I am a servant of the Secret Fire**, wielder of the flame of Anor. You cannot pass. The dark fire will not avail you, flame of Udûn. Go back to the Shadow! You cannot pass.'
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book II, Chapter 5 - "The Bridge of Khazad-dûm"</sub>

> But when Ar-Pharazôn set foot upon the shores of Aman the Blessed, **the Valar laid down their Guardianship and called upon the One,** and the world was changed.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Appendix A - "Annals of Kings and Rulers"</sub>

And to complete this answer a bit, here are some other instances of Tolkien using "the One" to refer to Eru. (I'm limiting this list to instances of characters using it in-universe, as if we start including Tolkien's letters and essays this list will get really long.)

> But Erendis denied his words, saying: "Such gifts as come from the Valar, and through them **from the One,** are to be loved for themselves now, and in all nows. They are not given for barter, for more or for better. The Edain remain mortal Men, Aldarion, great though they be: and we cannot dwell in the time that is to come, lest we lose our now for a phantom of our own design."
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Aldarion and Erendis"</sub>

> Behold! The darkness that is to come is filled with hatred for us, but it hates you no less. The Great Sea will not be too wide for its wings, if it is suffered to come to full growth.
> **Manwë keep you under the One,** and send fair wind to your sails.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Aldarion and Erendis"</sub>

> This oath shall stand in memory of the glory of the Land of the Star, and of the faith of Elendil the Faithful, in the keep­ing of those who sit upon the thrones of the West and of **the One who is above all thrones for ever.**
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "Cirion and Eorl"</sub>

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Yup, typo. Thanks. Also fwiw I wrote this answer prior to noticing that you had written an answer. Began writing it before you posted and never refreshed the page.

Comment: No worries, I suspected that was the case. :-) You got a bunch of extra quotes, though...

Comment: Gah, I realise that somehow I got a misquote of Adar's line, saying 'children' instead of 'creation'. Does take the wind out of the sails of my answer a bit... :-(